# Is there a need for thenif besides elseif?

Tags: programming-languages

For nested if constructs, some languages provide constructs similar to

```
if Bexp1 then C1
  elseif Bexp2 then C2
  ...
  elseif Bexpn then Cn
else Cn+1
endif
```

All I have seen provide `elseif`. I wonder why not further provide `thenif`? Is there a need for `thenif`?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly would this `thenif` accomplish?

Comment: More to the point, what would it accomplish that simply putting an **if** into the **then** block wouldn't?

Comment: We have this already.  It's called "and".  Some languages call it "&&".

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a need for `thenif`?

Since no mainstream language has such a construct, the answer to your question must be "no".

There again, there's no need for `elseif` either, as C-like languages get by with `else if`. So just because it's not needed doesn't mean it couldn't exist.

So should it exist? Since it's purpose would be to assist with writing nested `if`'s, it's worth remembering that the latter often add to both cyclomatic complexity and to poor readability. So if nested `if`'s are to be avoided (as a rule of thumb), then there seems little benefit to adding `thenif` to any language.

Comment: I've never seen an `elseif` in a C-like language. I've seen them in languages like Python and Ruby where there **is** a need - you can't use `else if` because `else` does not apply on the next statement like in C - it applies until the a block ends with dedent in Python or `end` in Ruby. This measn that without `elif`/`elsif` you'd have to nest the following `else if`s.

Comment: @IdanArye I'm not sure `elseif` is needed for Python but, as you say, it does make sense for languages that use `end` etc.

Comment: It's needed for python, because otherwise you'll have to indent more and more for each else-if. Compare [this](http://pastebin.com/XZczkTiD) to [this](http://pastebin.com/W8cVjryq).

Comment: @IdanArye, sorry I wasn't clear. Python chooses to have an `elif`, but it isn't needed for that style of language. [This fake python example](https://gist.github.com/DavidArno/6da2717c0f0cb2608b91c9de546c97ef) would work just fine if the language worked that way.

Comment: This would require a special treatment to `else if`, which is not fundamentally different than the `elif` keyword.

Answer (score 5):

I think such a construct would be more confusing than useful.

Consider this piece of code:

```
if my_condition then
    if my_other_condition then
        do_1();
    else
        do_2();
    endif;
else
    do_3();
endif;
```

If we had a "thenif" keyword, we would be able to shorten that code like this:

```
if my_condition thenif my_other_condition then
    do_1();
else
    do_2();
else
    do_3();
endif;
```

The new version of the code makes it harder to answer important questions at a glance, such as:

- Which branches might be taken if `my_condition` is true?
- What happens if `my_other_condition` is evaluated and comes out as false?
- Which occurrence of `else` corresponds to which occurrence of `if`?

Comment: The only path through that makes any sense is for `thenif` to act as `and`, in which case `and` already covers things.